# Remove any row with at least 1 NA with PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe and I would like to remove any row countaining at least one NA.
I know how to do so only for one column (code below).

How to do the same for all columns of the dataframe?

##### Reproducible example

```
# Import modules
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Defining SparkContext
SparkContext.getOrCreate() 

# Defining SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Introduction au DataFrame") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Initiating DataFrame
values = [("1","2","3"), 
          ("NA","1", "2"), 
          ("4", "NA", "1")] 
columns = ['var1', 
           'var2', 
           'var3']
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, columns)

# Initial dataframe
df.show()
+----+----+----+
|var1|var2|var3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|  NA|   1|   2|
|   4|  NA|   1|
+----+----+----+

# Subset rows without NAs (column 'var1')
df.where(~col('var1').contains('NA')).show()
+----+----+----+
|var1|var2|var3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   4|  NA|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

##### My expected output

```
+----+----+----+
|var1|var2|var3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

##### What I also tried

I have tried the following but it seems that PySpark doesn't recognize NAs as in pandas.
It only recognizes `null` values.

```
df.na.drop().show()
df.select([count(when(isnan('var1'), True))]).show()
df.filter(df['var1'].isNotNull()).show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new = (df.na.replace({'NA': None})#Replace string NA with null
       .dropna()#Drop NA
      ).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
df.dropna().show()
```

you can specify the paramter in dropna method also:
if `how = 'any'` , then it's your case
or `how = 'all'` the row will be removed if all columns are null
how by default is 'any'

Comment: Unfortunately it outputs the very first table that I outputted in my example (with 3 rows). Does it also output the same table when you copy the code?

Comment: Ah , I understand it doesn't work that's true because NA is a string,

Comment: you can try this one df.where(~((col('var1').contains('NA')) | (col('var2').contains('NA')) | (col('var3').contains('NA')))).show()

Comment: Thank you but I was more searching for an automatic method working on any dataset whatever its dimensions. I appreciate your help :)